# How using python (pandas/for loop) i can get result table like this?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have 2 DataFrames:

df_1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xxfq.png)

df_2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UwWR.png)

need to go through each cell on "code" from [df_1] and check it with [df_2] and compare it with the rank starting from the lowest, write the result in [df_3]

Need to get this result table

df_3
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaXaC.png)

I don't get it how i can do this using python+pandas? Pls help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see [Ask] to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: And [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also don't think your question format is right, but I answered because the question itself is an interesting issue. I hope you will ask good questions next time.

**Example Code**

we need minimal example as text. i remake more minial example and provide by code

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'smth': ['RB', 'Supp', 'DX RT', 'Fk', 'CZFO', 'Supp_t', 'RK', 'rec', 'commerc', 'Supp_t'], 
         'code': ['HC-1343958', 'HC-1343958', 'HC-1340305', 'HC-1340305', 'HC-1107001', 'HC-1107001', 'HC-1107001', 'HC-1135154', 'HC-1135154', 'HC-1135154'], 
         'product_name': ['ERXY3-400', 'ERXY3-400', 'BWH/S 100 Level PRO', 'BWH/S 100 Level PRO', 'GWH 12 Fonte', 'GWH 12 Fonte', 'GWH 12 Fonte', 'BEC/ETER-1500', 'BEC/ETER-1503', 'BEC/ETER-1505'], 
         'digit': [3, 2, 20, 1, 1, 17, 78, 246, 10, 23], 
         'changes': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
data2 = {'smth': ['rec', 'Supp', 'Supp_t', 'RK', 'CZFO', 'RB'], 'rank': [2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

df1

```
    smth    code        product_name            digit   changes
0   RB      HC-1343958  ERXY3-400               3       1
1   Supp    HC-1343958  ERXY3-400               2       1
2   DX RT   HC-1340305  BWH/S 100 Level PRO     20      1
3   Fk      HC-1340305  BWH/S 100 Level PRO     1       1
4   CZFO    HC-1107001  GWH 12 Fonte            1       1
5   Supp_t  HC-1107001  GWH 12 Fonte            17      1
6   RK      HC-1107001  GWH 12 Fonte            78      1
7   rec     HC-1135154  BEC/ETER-1500           246     1
8   commerc HC-1135154  BEC/ETER-1503           10      1
9   Supp_t  HC-1135154  BEC/ETER-1505           23      1
```

df2:

```
    smth    rank
0   rec     2
1   Supp    4
2   Supp_t  6
3   RK      8
4   CZFO    9
5   RB      10
```

**Code**

mapping by df2 and groupby idxmin.

and boolean indexing by result

```
m = dict(df2.values)
idxmin = df1['smth'].map(m).groupby(df1['code']).idxmin()
out = df1[df1.index.isin(idxmin)]
```

out:

```
    smth    code        product_name    digit   changes
1   Supp    HC-1343958  ERXY3-400       2       1
5   Supp_t  HC-1107001  GWH 12 Fonte    17      1
7   rec     HC-1135154  BEC/ETER-1500   246     1
```